# I get AttributeError: 'DialogNote' object has no attribute 'dilog_window'

Tags: python, user-interface

Write "Notes" applications in python using the flet framework, clicking on the elf.btn_container button should open a dialog box, but instead I get the error AttributeError: 'DialogNote' object has no attribute 'dilog_window'. I divided the code into two files, in the first I have the main interface and in the second I have to find the dialog window interface

First file:

```
import flet as ft
from dialogUi import DialogNote


class NoteApp(ft.UserControl):
    def __init__(self, page):
        super().__init__()

        self.page = page

        self.BG = "#2E4053"
        self.dlg = DialogNote()


    def build(self):


        def open_dlg(e):
            self.page.dialog = self.dlg.dilog_window
            self.dlg.dilog_window.open = True
            self.page.update()


        self.note_column = ft.Column(width=480,height=450)

        self.btn_container = ft.Container(
            width=480,height=90,bgcolor=self.BG,
            content=ft.Stack(
                [
                    ft.FloatingActionButton(icon=ft.icons.ADD, bottom=15,right=15, on_click=open_dlg)
                ]
            )
        )

        self.main_container = ft.Container(
            width=480,height=543,bgcolor=self.BG,border_radius=20,
            content=ft.Column(
                [
                    self.note_column,
                    self.btn_container
                ]
            )
        )

        return ft.Column([self.main_container])



def main(page: ft.Page):
    """
        WINDOW SETTINGS
    """
    page.window_width = 500
    page.window_height = 600
    page.window_center()

    app = NoteApp(page=page)
    page.add(app)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ft.app(target=main)
```

Second file:

```
import flet as ft


class DialogNote(ft.UserControl):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def build(self):
        self.title = ft.TextField("Title")
        self.text = ft.TextField("Text")

        self.dilog_window = ft.AlertDialog(
            content=ft.Column(
                [
                    self.title,
                    self.text,
                ]
            )
        )

        return self.dilog_window
```

i tried to take out self.dilog_window for build

Comment: You misspelled "dialog_window", you left out the "a".

Comment: I really made a mistake, but the error is not from the correct variable name? In both files I wrote dilog_window

Comment: `dilog_window` is only added when you call `self.dlg.build()`, but you never call this.

Comment: i did like this
def open_dlg(e):
             self.page.dialog = self.dlg.build()
             self.dlg.build().open = True
             self.page.update()

but now I have another error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'current'

Comment: I don't see `current` anywhere in the posted code.